# Cloudant: couch returned 500

Tags: node.js, database, couchdb, cloudant

Getting cloudant error on find query:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "isValid": {
         "$eq": true
      }
   }
}
```

```
Could not find document query: "{exit,lru} couch returned 500"
Could not find document query: "{exit,noproc} couch returned 500"
```

Trying to execute simple find query and getting this error. The expected result should be returned result of the query.

Comment: It's impossible to help you without some more info. What did your query look like? Can you give some example documents?

Comment: @xpqz  I have updated the question, this is the simple query executing on Cloudant.

Comment: Can you please open a Cloudant support ticket so that we can look at logs etc. Many thanks, Cloudant